# Replacing all char's in String, except for whitespaces

Tags: java, regex, replace, whitespace

I'm trying to replace all char's in a String with "-", except for the whitespaces.

```
"This is a test" should become "---- -- - ----" and "Test" should become "----"
```

It's probably a simple REGEX, but i'm not able to see how to do it, regex is not my strong suit.

Comment: Down-vote from me. Regex might not be your strong suit, but this seems relatively easy to research. I would at least expect to see an attempt in the question.

Comment: I know, i had done several attempts, in most of them I tried to do it seperately, first replacing all white spaces, and then only replacing the char's, but none of them were succesfull. Next time i'll include my attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
String repl = input.replaceAll("[^ ]", "-");
```

OR:

```
String repl = input.replaceAll("\\S", "-");
```

Here `\\S` will anything but a white-space whereas `[^ ]` will match anything but a space.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: I know the answer was given, I just wanted to give you a resource for future regex style issues. This site http://www.regexr.com will give you both a live viewing of your tests, and resources to help you figure out what you should be doing. it is a great one, bookmark it.